# Fastest and/or most pythonic way to convert string into a number

Tags: python

first of all, I've seen quite a few questions related to this (convert string to float, etc etc), but I need something more generic, which I could not find (so I hope this will also help out other people with a similar problem). 
I have made a solution, but am wondering whether it is the best solution in terms of 1) performance and 2) pythonic elegance.

The problem in short:

- I get data from a variety of sources, these are made into a list with
  dicts (as a row/column table setup).
- The variety means that I cannot
  rely on a fixed input type (basically they might be string, boolean,
  int, float) but the user can designate which columns (keys in the
  dict) are values.
- Which I then need to convert to actual value types (we're talking about 100s of millions of rows of data here, so performance is rather key).
- If the input is not a real number (like: 'aaa'), then it should return None.
- There might be currency symbols and thousand separators (which need to be removed), and decimal separators (which need to be replaced by the standard dot, if it's not a dot)

So what have I made:

```
import ast
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, bool): # make boolean into a 0/1 value
            if s:
                result = 1
            else:
                result = 0
    elif isinstance(s, NumberTypes): # keep numbers as/is
        result = s
    else: # convert a string
        # prepare the string for conversion
        if currency_sign != '':
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')
        if thousand_sep != '':
            s = s.replace(thousand_sep, '')
        if decimal_sep != '.':
            s = s.replace(decimal_sep, '.')        
        s = s.strip()
        # convert the string
        if s == '':
            result = None
        else:
            try:
                # convert the string by a safe evaluation
                result = ast.literal_eval(s)
                # check if result of the evaluation is a number type
                if not isinstance(result, NumberTypes):
                    result = None
            except ValueError:
                # if the conversion gave an error, the string is not a number
                result = None
    return result
```

You can test it by:

```
mk_value(True)
mk_value(1234)
mk_value(1234.56)
mk_value('1234')
mk_value('1234.56')
mk_value('1,234.56') # without an explicit decimal separator this is not a number
mk_value('1.234.567,89 EUR', currency_sign='EUR', thousand_sep='.', decimal_sep=',') # all exceptions
```

So this works (as far as I can see); but is this the best/most pythonic way? Are there faster ways? Should I look into Cython for this? Any ideas on improving this would be really helpful!

BR

Carst

Edit: I've updated my code based on the suggestions by Andrew and WoLpH. It now looks like this:

```
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, bool): # make boolean into a 0/1 value
            if s:
                result = 1
            else:
                result = 0
    elif isinstance(s, NumberTypes): # keep numbers as/is
        result = s
    else: # convert a string
        # prepare the string for conversion
        if currency_sign:
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')
        if thousand_sep:
            s = s.replace(thousand_sep, '')
        if decimal_sep != '.':
            s = s.replace(decimal_sep, '.')        
        s = s.strip()
        # convert the string
        if not s: # if the string is empty, it's not a number
            result = None
        else:
            try: # try int
                result = int(s)
            except ValueError:
                try: # if there's an error, try float
                    result = float(s)
                except ValueError:                    
                    # if the conversion gave an error, the string is not a number
                    result = None
    return result
```

the previous code's performance was this:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value(1234)", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.050575971603393555
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value(1234.56)", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.07073187828063965
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value('1234')", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.8333430290222168
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value('1234.56')", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.8230760097503662
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.9358179569244385
```

the new code's performance:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value(1234)", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.04723405838012695
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value(1234.56)", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.06952905654907227
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value('1234')", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.1798090934753418
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value('1234.56')", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.45616698265075684
>>> timeit.timeit("mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')", 'from __main__ import mk_value', number=100000)
0.5290899276733398
```

So that's a lot faster: almost twice as fast for the most complex one and much much faster for the int (I guess as it's the first in the try/except logic)! Really great, thanks for your input.

I'm going to leave it open for now to see if someone has a brilliant idea on how to improve more :) At the very least I hope this will help other people in the future (it must be a very common issue)

Comment: In terms of performance, have you considered adding an int/float/bool cast as default and fallling back to parsing manually? That could help a lot. If you're talking about lots of rows however, Cython could help a lot already but you would want to do the entire loop in Cython so you don't convert the values between Python and Cython for every iteration.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for this.

Comment: Thanks @WoLpH, i'll make a variant where I do a series of try/excepts instead of the AST.literal_eval and test the difference in performance.

Comment: @andrewcooke: you're probably right, to be honest I was not really aware of it (and yes: it's more a review/improvement than a problem); I cannot move it there, can I?

Comment: i couldn't work out how to move it (the close popup lets you move to various places, but not codereview).

Comment: The most pythonic way is to see if PyPI has something that does what you want :)

Comment: @Nirk: i could not find anything for this on PyPi :) If you have suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Maybe: `if isinstance (s, bool): return int (s)` and `elif isinstance (s, numbers.Number): return s`

Comment: And: `result = s.translate (string.maketrans (decimal_sep, '.') If decimal_sep else None, thousand_sep).replace (currency_sign, '')` to reduce the logic and number of rellacements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be slightly more Pythonic imho, but I'm not sure about the best solution yet.

## Code

### `benchmark.py`

```
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8 :
import timeit
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

def timer(func, mod):
    import_ = 'from %s import mk_value' % mod
    time = timeit.timeit(func, import_, number=100000)
    ms = 1000 * time
    us = 1000 * ms

    if func[40:]:
        func_short = func[:37] + '...'
    else:
        func_short = func

    print '%(mod)s.%(func_short)-40s %(ms)6dms %(us)12dμs' % locals()

for mod in 'abcd':
    timer("mk_value(1234)", mod)
    timer("mk_value(1234.56)", mod)
    timer("mk_value('1234')", mod)
    timer("mk_value('1234.56')", mod)
    timer("mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')", mod)
    timer("mk_value('1.234.567,89 EUR', currency_sign='EUR', "
        "thousand_sep='.', decimal_sep=',')", mod)
```

### `a.py`

```
import ast
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, bool): # make boolean into a 0/1 value
            if s:
                result = 1
            else:
                result = 0
    elif isinstance(s, NumberTypes): # keep numbers as/is
        result = s
    else: # convert a string
        # prepare the string for conversion
        if currency_sign != '':
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')
        if thousand_sep != '':
            s = s.replace(thousand_sep, '')
        if decimal_sep != '.':
            s = s.replace(decimal_sep, '.')        
        s = s.strip()
        # convert the string
        if s == '':
            result = None
        else:
            try:
                # convert the string by a safe evaluation
                result = ast.literal_eval(s)
                # check if result of the evaluation is a number type
                if not isinstance(result, NumberTypes):
                    result = None
            except ValueError:
                # if the conversion gave an error, the string is not a number
                result = None
    return result
```

### `b.py`

```
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, bool): # make boolean into a 0/1 value
            if s:
                result = 1
            else:
                result = 0
    elif isinstance(s, NumberTypes): # keep numbers as/is
        result = s
    else: # convert a string
        # prepare the string for conversion
        if currency_sign:
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')
        if thousand_sep:
            s = s.replace(thousand_sep, '')
        if decimal_sep != '.':
            s = s.replace(decimal_sep, '.')        
        s = s.strip()
        # convert the string
        if not s: # if the string is empty, it's not a number
            result = None
        else:
            try: # try int
                result = int(s)
            except ValueError:
                try: # if there's an error, try float
                    result = float(s)
                except ValueError:                    
                    # if the conversion gave an error, the string is not a number
                    result = None
    return result
```

### `c.pyx`

```
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, bool): # make boolean into a 0/1 value
        if s:
            result = 1
        else:
            result = 0

    elif isinstance(s, NumberTypes): # keep numbers as/is
        result = s

    else: # convert a string
        # prepare the string for conversion
        if currency_sign:
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')
        if thousand_sep:
            s = s.replace(thousand_sep, '')
        if decimal_sep != '.':
            s = s.replace(decimal_sep, '.')        
        s = s.strip()
        # convert the string
        if not s: # if the string is empty, it's not a number
            result = None
        else:
            try: # try int
                result = int(s)
            except ValueError:
                try: # if there's an error, try float
                    result = float(s)
                except ValueError:                    
                    # if the conversion gave an error, the string is not a number
                    result = None
    return result
```

### `d.pyx`

```
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def  mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, bool): # make boolean into a 0/1 value
        if s:
            result = 1
        else:
            result = 0

    elif isinstance(s, NumberTypes): # keep numbers as/is
        result = s

    elif s:
        if currency_sign:
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')

        result = _mk_value(s, currency_sign, thousand_sep, decimal_sep)

    else:
        result = None

    return result

cdef object _mk_value(char *s, char *currency_sign, char *thousand_sep, char *decimal_sep):
    cdef int i=0, j=0
    result = None

    while s[i]:
        if s[i] == decimal_sep[0]:
            s[j] = '.'
            j += 1
        elif s[i] == thousand_sep[0]:
            pass
        elif s[i] == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            s[j] = s[i]
            j += 1

        i += 1

    # convert the string
    if not s: # if the string is empty, it's not a number
        result = None
    else:
        try: # try int
            result = int(s)
        except ValueError:
            try: # if there's an error, try float
                result = float(s)
            except ValueError:                    
                # if the conversion gave an error, the string is not a number
                pass
    return result
```

## Results

```
a.mk_value(1234)                               27ms        27526μs
a.mk_value(1234.56)                            42ms        42097μs
a.mk_value('1234')                            502ms       502109μs
a.mk_value('1234.56')                         520ms       520395μs
a.mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')      570ms       570749μs
a.mk_value('1.234.567,89 EUR', currency...    627ms       627456μs
b.mk_value(1234)                               27ms        27082μs
b.mk_value(1234.56)                            40ms        40014μs
b.mk_value('1234')                             94ms        94444μs
b.mk_value('1234.56')                         276ms       276519μs
b.mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')      315ms       315310μs
b.mk_value('1.234.567,89 EUR', currency...    374ms       374861μs
c.mk_value(1234)                               11ms        11482μs
c.mk_value(1234.56)                            22ms        22765μs
c.mk_value('1234')                             69ms        69251μs
c.mk_value('1234.56')                         176ms       176908μs
c.mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')      226ms       226709μs
c.mk_value('1.234.567,89 EUR', currency...    285ms       285431μs
d.mk_value(1234)                               11ms        11483μs
d.mk_value(1234.56)                            22ms        22355μs
d.mk_value('1234')                             69ms        69151μs
d.mk_value('1234.56')                         169ms       169364μs
d.mk_value('1,234.56', thousand_sep=',')      187ms       187460μs
d.mk_value('1.234.567,89 EUR', currency...    233ms       233935μs
```

Comment: Thanks (the if decimal_sep part only cannot work that way, because decimal_sep is standard '.' as in: floats will always have it), but i will try this + replacing the literal_eval part with the andrew's try/except suggestion)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help & feedback! My Cython skills are very much lacking (on my to-do list), I'm really curious to a Cython solution for this (great learning occasion!)

Comment: The Cython solution is a bit tricky since you have variable types. Usually you get most effect from using native types but I'm doing parts in native C now to see if it helps a bit ;)

Comment: @Carst: I've tried a few things and this one seems the fastest so far. It could be optimized further if all loops would be done in C (there's a little bit of C/Python conversion here) but this should help a bit :)

Comment: @Carst: if you want to optimize a lot further, you would need to know the output variable type (i.e. integer, float). That assumption can help a lot.

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually, we do have a precision which we can use for formatting output from the converted values, but that would also be usable here indeed (i.e. precision 0=int, 1 or more float); for best performance, I would make then two different _mk_value objects for each type? (i.e. _mk_int and _mk_float) and execute the right one based on a lookup of the column? Feel slightly stupid now, as that would probably also optimize the python code too. Thanks! Gonna tinker with this!

Comment: `c.pyx`? Isn't `d` the only one that actually uses Cython?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: correct, but even when not explicitly using Cython you can still notice a speedup as you can see in the results.

Comment: I was just wondering why you gave that filename a .pyx extension.

Comment: The .pyx extension makes the file go through Cython instead of plain Python which can help the performance in some cases. In this case there is quite a noticable speedup without any code changes.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it with early-out logic and raising an exception to indicate failure:

```
import types
NumberTypes = (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType)

def mk_value(s, currency_sign='', thousand_sep='', decimal_sep='.'):
    if isinstance(s, NumberTypes):
        # Already in the desired form.
        return s

    if isinstance(s, str):
        # Prepare the string for conversion.
        if currency_sign:
            s = s.replace(currency_sign, '')
        if thousand_sep:
            s = s.replace(thousand_sep, '')
        if decimal_sep != '.':
            s = s.replace(decimal_sep, '.')        
        # stripping the string isn't necessary either...

    # Convert the string.
    # The empty string case is already handled;
    # "special cases aren't special enough".
    # This also handles bools naturally; might be slower,
    # but bools oughtn't be the common case anyway.
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s)
        # If that didn't work either, let the exception propagate.
```

Comment: much nicer.  from 2.6 onwards there's an ABC for numbers, so you could just do `isinstance(s, Number)` - http://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html